How to make this countdown timer work in seconds and not minutes
I'm working on a digital signage program that allows for scripting to accomplish more advanced stuff. The downside is that their repository is dookie and not publicly available, so, sorry, can't post it. In this script I know that RT.inow only provides timecode up to minutes. I'm doing a lot of shooting in the dark. Doesn't help that there's no way to test code live or debug or anything. It's just put code in a binding path and hope it plays nice.
It doesn't help that I know just enough coding to get in trouble.
Here's the code I have already made that will take a data list with iXML in it, look at the start and end times of a listed session and calculate the remaining hours and minutes.
public function init():void
{
  self.addBindListener(["self.rawRows","RT.inow"],onRowsChanged);
}
private function onRowsChanged(bd:*):void
{
  var dl = box.find("EVENT INFORMATION");
  if(!bd.at(0))
  {
    return;
  }
  var rows = bd.at(0);
  var result = [];
  var now = bd.at(1)*60000;
  for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
  {
    var data = rows[i].data;
    var start = Utils.toDate(rows[i].getString("StartDateTime"));
    var end = Utils.toDate(rows[i].getString("EndDateTime"));
    var starttime = Utils.toInt((start.getTime()-now)/1000);
    var endtime = Utils.toInt((end.getTime()-now)/1000);

    var remaininglabel = "";

    var remaining_hours = Utils.toInt(endtime%86400/3600);
    var remaining_minutes = Utils.toInt(endtime%3600/60);



    if(remaining_hours && remaining_minutes)
    {
      remaininglabel = remaining_hours + " hr " + remaining_minutes + " min remaining.";
    }
    else if(remaining_hours)
    {
      remaininglabel = remaining_hours + " hr " + " remaining.";
    }
    else if(remaining_minutes)
    {
      remaininglabel = remaining_minutes + " min ";
    }
    else
    {
      remaininglabel = "";
    }

    data["remaining"] = remaininglabel;
    result.push(data);
  }
  dl.source.fill(result);
}

I thought it would be as easy as adding a seconds variable and adding another else if to include seconds. But then I found out that RT.inow doesn't calculate seconds. Only minutes.
So what else to I need to do to force this to update on seconds instead on RT.inow and the iXML rows change so that I can get hours, minutes and seconds? Any thoughts?
